# Testing function that uses database schema with PHPUnit

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit

I am writing a function that involves checking the schema of a database and comparing it to the schema of another. To do this I am calling a function that does a query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. Based on this further checks are implemented in PHP.

I'm wondering what might be the best way to unit-test this function:

1. Could mocking be a solution?
2. or abstracting more functions?

I'm using Laravel, PHP, PHPUnit and MySQL/SQLite.

Comment: It depends on how your code is structured really, but you definitely want to be mocking the schema response and just testing the PHP side of things.